# Hiding UINavigationBar in iOS7 while poping a Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikit, uinavigationbar

So I have two UIViewControllers - VC1 with the property of `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` and VC2 with the same property set to `NO`.

I do the following in the VC2:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        // Showing navigation bar for VC2
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
         // Hiding navigation bar for VC1
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    }
```

It hides the `NavigationBar` for the VC1 perfectly. However, when I use the so called `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` (that is, sliding the `UIViewController` with my finger to the right to pop it) the `navigationBar` hides immediately, even the 95% of the view is visible:

[image] [image]

Putting the code to `viewDidDisappear` doesn't help either, because the `NavBar` stays on the view (probably because it's never called). This is **NOT** what I need:
[image] [image]

What is the best possible workaround in this situation? How do we make the `navBar` **stay** on the VC2 while it is being slide out to the right and **not** appear on the VC1 at all?

Comment: Try with **viewdiddisappear**

Comment: @KumarKl Check out my edit on the post, already did that with no avail.

Comment: it would be great if you put image or screenshot of it.

Comment: Check whether any call back method is getting called after completing sliding like didFinishSliding:. If so add your navigation bar hide/show logic inside that method

Comment: @Ab'initio that's exactly what I would be looking for but I didn't find any yet.

Comment: You have to make custom Navigation bar, as native is not working according to your specification.

Comment: is it your requirement https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7R9PH1nPT2vMFlWam40S2VtZkk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ab'initio that's pretty close, but the fact is that the `navBar` should **never** appear on VC1 and should kind of _stick_ to VC2.

Comment: Then I think it would better to use custom image view as navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer proved to be really simple, though it is undocumented anywhere (or at least I didn't find  it yet).

Instead of `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO` one should use `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]` - this works flawlessly with `iOS7`'s `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` which is a part of new `animatedTransitions` API. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` in VC2 `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` and

Place it in VC1 `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

I think, it may meet your requirement

Thanks,

Satya

Comment: Didn't help as well. It's a surprise there is no good solution for this yet.